# Nodejs - Callback function only executing if error exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback, invoke

I'm trying to write a function to connect to a wifi network using this node library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wifi) but it seems that whenever I execute this function, unless an error is actually present, the callback is skipped entirely. I might be misinterpreting how callbacks work, but shouldn't it execute even in the event that there is no error detected?

```js
function ConnectToNetwork(networkName: string, networkPassword: string) {
  // Connect to a network
  wifi.disconnect();
  wifi.connect({ ssid: networkName, password: networkPassword }, function (err) {
    //This is not logged when no error is present
    console.log("callback?");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Couldn't connect to network");
      return createFailureWindow();
    }
      //Shouldn't this part of the function be invoked if there is no error?
      UpdateCurrentConnections();
      createSuccessWindow();
      console.log("Connected");

  });
}
```

Comment: Yes it should run after it connects. Are you sure it is connecting ?

Comment: Yes, it's connecting as intended, but whenever it does the callback never executes. Have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in disconnect callback?

```js
function ConnectToNetwork(networkName: string, networkPassword: string) {
  // Connect to a network
  wifi.disconnect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("Disconnected");
  wifi.connect({ ssid: networkName, password: networkPassword }, function (err) {
    //This is not logged when no error is present
    console.log("callback?");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log("Couldn't connect to network");
      return createFailureWindow();
    }
      //Shouldn't this part of the function be invoked if there is no error?
      UpdateCurrentConnections();
      createSuccessWindow();
      console.log("Connected");

  });
});
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. Disconnect encounters no errors and the same is happening even if I comment disconnect() out.